# Can not log to mysql database in spring mvc with log4j

Tags: mysql, spring, log4j

I need to log information for my application to database. Database logs are not getting written to tables when I run on server in Spring MVC application (HelloWorldController.class), but I can log when run java application (TestJavaApp.java). I do this example at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm. Here is my code

log4j.properties

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, DB

# Define the DB appender
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender

# Set JDBC Options
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/prdt
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=root

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO logs(date, logger, level, message) VALUES('%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS}','%C','%p','%m')

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.alpertngo.springmvcxml.yori.web.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello from spring 4 MVC");
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            logger.info("INFO LOG " + i);
            logger.error("ERROR LOG "+i);
        }
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

TestJavaApp.java

```
package com.alpertngo.springmvcxml.yori.web.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestJavaApp {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestJavaApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("INFO LOG");
        logger.error("ERROR LOG");

        System.out.println("Success!");

    }
}
```

I forgot something or need any configure. Could I have a solution for this or have an example for log to database in spring mvc. Here is result when run java application

[image]